# ruby installation issue in centos

Tags: ruby, centos, rubygems, tmux, tmuxinator

I have installed ruby in centos 7. Then i try to ran the tmuxinator it gives me below error. How to solve this issue?

```
/opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

output for **ruby -v**   is 
ruby 2.2.8p477 (2017-09-14 revision 59906) [x86_64-linux]

output for  **rpm -q ruby** is 
ruby-2.0.0.648-30.el7.x86_64

I try to remove old dependencies using **rpm -e ruby** , but it gives me below error.
error: Failed dependencies:
        /usr/bin/ruby is needed by (installed) rubygems-2.0.14.1-30.el7.noarch
        /usr/bin/ruby is needed by (installed) ruby-irb-2.0.0.648-30.el7.noarch
        /usr/bin/ruby is needed by (installed) rubygem-rdoc-4.0.0-30.el7.noarch

Comment: can you post the output of `ruby -v` and `rpm -q ruby` please

Comment: This is using the RHSCL correct? You have to setup an env for those post-installation i believe. Better to use other tools for most use cases.

Comment: what do you mean RHCL and what are those env ?